# $f$ is a primitive polynomial in $Z[x]$. Show that the intersection of $fQ[x]$ with $Z[x]$ is $fZ[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials

> Let $f \in Z[X]$ primitive. Show that $(fQ[X]) \cap Z[X] = fZ[X]$.

Thanks!

I think I solved it.

Here is my solution:

Clearly $fZ[x] \subset (fQ[X]) \cap Z[X]$, so we need to prove the opposite.

Let $a \in (fQ[X]) \cap Z[X]$, then $a = fg$ for some non-constant polynomial $g \in Q[X]$.

$g \in Q[X]$, there is $c \in Q$ such that $cg \in Z[X]$ and primitive.

$h = cg, g = c^{-1}h, a = c^{-1}fh$

Can apply Gauss's Lemma: $f$ primitive, $h$ primitive implies $fh$ primitive.

It's easy to show that $c^{-1} \in Z$, so $g \in Z[X]$, $a = fg \in fZ[X]$

Comment: [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_(polynomial)), or its proof.